# Is there a way to resolve rotational ambiguity if I know the direction of the z axis?

Tags: rotation, pose, apriltags

I’m trying to use apriltag to detect tags that are face up on a tables surface, therefore I am always able to determine the tags z forward vector relative to the camera. I’m unfortunately getting some flickering of tags and wanted to know if there is any way to improve this. Is there a way to acquire both rotation matrices and pick the best one manually or is there any way to adjust the resulting rotation matrix using the z axis information?

For now I simply check the rotations forward and discard it if it to too far off of the known forward vector, however this results in approx 50% of my readings getting discarded. A better solution would be to look at both results and select the best one myself.